# Apache Geode Native Client Cache::createRegion: region exists in local cache

Tags: gemfire, geode

To answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48622814/c-sharp-winform-delegates-for-n-subforms) I am using the [Pivotal Native Client](https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-gemfire/#/releases/5469) to create many [local client caches](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/14/developing/region_options/region_types.html) so each local client cache would have their own `Listener`. I come up against a problem which is that [from the QuickStart example](https://github.com/apache/geode-native/blob/develop/quickstart/csharp/DistributedSystem.cs#L65) after the cache, pool and region factory are created as default no matter what kind of `RegionShortcut` is used for example `.LOCAL` or any other

```
RegionFactory rf = c.CreateRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.LOCAL);
```

then:

`IRegion<string, string> region = rf.SetPoolName(poolName).Create<string, string>("exampleRegion");`

is fine for the 1st instance of a client cache, but once any other is attempted as another local client cache then that code above gives the error:

`An unhandled exception of type 'Apache.Geode.Client.RegionExistsException' occurred in Pivotal.Gemfire.dll`

`Additional information: Cache::createRegion: "exampleRegion" region exists in local cache`

So how can you create many local client caches within the same C# project?

Comment: This looks like a bug.  Recommend reporting it to the user's Geode list

Comment: @WesWilliams thx 4 comment. Shall do so. Tho I guess new cache cd be done by new thread for each cache instead of new object instance... but then for a high freq app there will be even more context switches. Wd prefer Geode to manage context switches?

Comment: In another case of the "region exists" error I had init the region before as `<string, string>` and was trying to connect as `<string, object>`

Answer (score 0):

This happened again when the use of the region factory, and trying to subscribe to keys in a region was being done on a separate (background) thread to the cache and region initialization.